# string find method does not find first letter

Tags: c++, string

I am implementing a very simple c++ code to demo find method. The letters in the second string should be present in the first string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void solution(string str1, string str2){
  int size1 = str1.size();
  int size2 = str2.size();

  if(size1 != size2){
    cout<<"not equal";
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i <size2; i++){
    if (str1.find(str2[i],0)){
      cout<<"found "<<str2[i]<<endl;
    }
  }
}


int main(){

  solution("abcd", "dacb");
  return 0;
}
```

I always get an output like

```
found d
found c
found b
```

find() never matches the first letter of the first string (the string on which the find method is implemented).

Could anyone point the reason? I have tried looking up many sources. Am I missing anything about find() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string::find()` returns the index of the character (or string) found. `'a'` is located at index 0, which evaluates to false. Hence the behavior. You need to change the `if` statement to check if the returned index is equal to `std::string::npos` instead. Something like this:

```
if(str.find(str2[i]) != string::npos)
```

**Note: You don't need to include `stdio.h` because you are not using `printf`s.**